# What is the best way to create/reverse a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I'm a beginner at programming and I've learnt how to reverse a linked list.
Below is the code I used to make a linked list with random values and reverse it. I was wondering what the best way to do this would be. Thanks for your suggestions! Have a great day!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

// node
typedef struct node{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
}node;

// functions
node *reversedList(node *head);
void printList(node *head);
node *create(int size);

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));
    // ........
}

node *reversedList(node *curr)
{
    // a->b->c->d
    // d->c->b->a
    node *previous = NULL;
    while(curr->next != NULL)
    {
        node *curr_temp = curr->next;
        curr->next = previous;
        previous = curr;
        curr = curr_temp;
    }
    curr->next = previous;
    return curr;
}

void printList(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%d ",head->number);
    printList(head->next);
}

node *create(int size)
{
    if(size == 0)
        return NULL;
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->number = rand() % 10;
    n->next = create(size - 1);
    return n;   
}
```

Comment: Does your code have a problem, or does it work as expected?

Comment: Probably the best way to reverse a list is to make it doubly linked in the first place.  Then "reversing" the list is basically a no-op, you just view the final element as the first.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion. "best" can mean different things. Off-topic.

Comment: You need to define "best". Least memory, fastest add/remove, fastest traversal, easiest to implement... what? Linked lists with individually allocated nodes have overall very bad performance on modern computers.

Comment: I understand that this may just be a learning exercise with no practical value, but: if you're having to reverse a linked list, that linked list was probably the wrong choice of data structure to begin with.  (And since it's an impractical problem, my perversely favorite way to reverse a linked list is with a recursive algorithm, which is of course *dreadfully* impractical as it uses as many stack frames as there are nodes in the list.)

Comment: Reversing a linked list is _very easy_ and best done in a _loop_. It is an excellent data structure for this operation because it does not require moving anything. Don’t listen to nay-saying.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this because OP's code had a _bug_ that was fixed by responders. And, there are some very clear changes to be made. There are only a few ways to do this. And, many similar questions about linked lists get asked/answered without being marked "opinion based"

Comment: Except for (1) the bug and (2) the fact that the code is a bit incomplete, this might be better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CraigEstey given (1) and (2) then this wouldn't work on CR, complete working code is required.

Comment: @ThomasWard I think that was implied by what I said (e.g "_Except_ for"). And, we often field such questions here anyway. Ironically, OP had a bug in the code but didn't realize it (so, maybe, there's a bug in OP :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to reverse a singly-linked list is to reverse it without invoking undefined behavior

In your function `reversedList` you do not check whether the passed pointer `curr` is equal to `NULL`. So the expression in the while loop

```
while(curr->next != NULL)
```

can invoke undefined behavior.

The function can be defined the following way

```
node * reversedList( node *head )
{
    // a->b->c->d
    // d->c->b->a

    node *curr = head;
    head = NULL;

    while ( curr != NULL )
    {
        Node *tmp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        tmp->next = head;
        head = tmp; 
    }

    return head;
}
```

Pay attention to that the parameter of the recursive function `printList` should be declared with the qualifier `const` because the list is not changed within the function

```
void printList(cosnt node *head);
```

I would declare and define the recursive function the following way

```
FILE * printList( const node *head, FILE *fp )
{
    if ( head )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d ", head->number );
    
        printList( head->next, fp );
    }

    return fp;
}
```

and in main you could write

```
fputc( '\n', printList( head, stdout ) );
```

Using such a function you could output the list in any stream including a file stream.

Comment: What does it mean to invoke undefined behaviour? I checked if  ```(curr->next != NULL)``` inside the while loop. How is this different from  saying ```(curr != NULL )``` if ```curr``` and ```curr->next``` represent the same values?

Comment: @Diwas_lufy It means that when you use a null pointer to access memory then the result of such an operation is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

*Side note:* Curiously, you did an iterative solution for reversal, but did a *recursive* solutions for `create` and `printList`

Your function is pretty close to optimal.

But, you fetched `curr->next` *twice*. Admittedly, with an optimizer, there should be no extra speed penalty.

But, I'd simplify that. And, I think a `for` loop can be cleaner:

```
node *
reversedFor(node *curr)
{
    // a->b->c->d
    // d->c->b->a
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *next;

    for (;  curr != NULL;  curr = next) {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
    }

    return prev;
}
```

**Edit:** And, as Vlad mentioned, you don't check for `curr` being non-null before dereferencing it. So, my above refactoring fixed the bug with a bit of serendipity.

---

Here's what I'd to clean everything up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// node
typedef struct node {
    int number;
    struct node *next;
} node;

// functions
node *reversedList(node *head);
node *reversedFor(node *head);
void printList(node *head,const char *tag);
node *create(int size);
node *delList(node *head);

typedef node *(revfnc_p)(node *head);

void
dotest(revfnc_p fnc,const char *tag)
{
    node *list;

    printf("dotest: %s\n",tag);

    list = create(10);
    printList(list,"orig");

    list = fnc(list);
    printList(list,"revd");

    delList(list);
}

int
main(void)
{

    dotest(reversedList,"reversedList");
    dotest(reversedFor,"reversedFor");

    return 0;
}

node *
reversedList(node *curr)
{
    // a->b->c->d
    // d->c->b->a
    node *previous = NULL;

    while (curr->next != NULL) {
        node *curr_temp = curr->next;

        curr->next = previous;
        previous = curr;
        curr = curr_temp;
    }
    curr->next = previous;
    return curr;
}

node *
reversedFor(node *curr)
{
    // a->b->c->d
    // d->c->b->a
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *next;

    for (;  curr != NULL;  curr = next) {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
    }

    return prev;
}

void
printList(node *head,const char *tag)
{

    if (tag != NULL)
        printf("%s:",tag);

    for (node *curr = head;  curr != NULL;  curr = curr->next)
        printf(" %d",curr->number);

    printf("\n");
}

node *
create(int size)
{
    node *head = NULL;
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *curr;

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < size;  ++idx) {
        curr = malloc(sizeof(*curr));
        curr->number = idx;
        curr->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL)
            head = curr;
        else
            prev->next = curr;

        prev = curr;
    }

    return head;
}

node *
delList(node *curr)
{
    node *next;

    for (;  curr != NULL;  curr = next) {
        next = curr->next;
        free(curr);
    }

    return curr;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
dotest: reversedList
orig: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
revd: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
dotest: reversedFor
orig: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
revd: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```